# Two instances of blur.js possible?

Tags: jquery, blurry

I would like to use blur.js on two different elements with different sources. How can I achieve that?

My code so far:

```
 $('.blurry1').blurjs({
      source: '.source1',
      cache: false, 
      radius: 10,
      debug: 1,
 });

 $('.blurry2').blurjs({
      source: '.source2',
      cache: false, 
      radius: 10,
      debug: 1,
 });
```

Only the second function is executed correctly.

Comment: What does your HTML/CSS look like?

Comment: Check their home page, it has multiple examples on it: http://www.blurjs.com/

Comment: The problem is not, that we use two different divs where the blur function should be executed on (like on their website). The problem is the two sources from which the blurred image should be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done but it’s a bit of a hack as it relies on the setTimeout function to wait until the first blurjs function has finished.

```
$('#blurry1').blurjs({
    source: 'body',
    radius: 30,
    overlay: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)',
    cache: false
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#blurry2').blurjs({
        source: '#bg2',
        radius: 30,
        overlay: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)',
        cache: false
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This fork](https://github.com/korpirkor/Blur.js) of Blur.js by CezaryDanielNowak fixes the limitation imposed by the initial implementation and allows for multi-element blurring simultaneously - no need for setTimeout.