# cannot use multiple blurjs events

Tags: jquery, blur, blurry

I try to have multiple blur events in blurjs jquery plugin but it seems to just not work at all when using more than 1 blur events.

```
$('.target1').blurjs({
    overlay: 'rgba(0,100,100,0.1)',
    source: 'body',
    radius: 30
});

$('.target2').blurjs({
    overlay: 'rgba(100,55,255,.6)',
    source: 'body',
    radius: 10
});
```

when running both nothing happens, running only one works, any way to fix this?

Comment: It can be done with a time. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025702/two-instances-of-blur-js-possible/26927062#26927062

Comment: @VincentGauthier I'll try it later.  the thing is that instead of his issue, where only the second code runs, my issue is that neither run and it just doesn't do anything.  And I can't use google chrome's console because when I open the console it crashes google chrome from something in blurjs

Comment: @Jakertr00, I walking away from using JS library for the blur effects. I'm now using this CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034485/ios-7s-blurred-overlay-effect-using-css/18917308#18917308. It is working great and I can have more than one blur element per page.